# Migration causes self-answers from asker despite other authors actually posting

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, self-answer

I migrated this question, "[sudo does not allow me to run cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103950/sudo-does-not-allow-me-to-run-cp?noredirect=1)" from Stack Overflow to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13678/sudo-does-not-allow-me-to-run-cp).

The original on Stack Overflow had answers by two different users:

[Razor Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322900/razor-storm) and [Richo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182327/richo)

However, when the post appeared in Unix.SE the two answers are now showing as being left by the OP instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a good one - a negative result of a refactor of migrations.  We have found the issue and fixed it up - thanks for the report Kev!  All other side effects of this refactor are positively awesome :)

Comment: Is this one of the awesome side effects? [Why are migrated questions being shown as closed and migrated instead of just migrated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92479)