# Why are migrated questions being shown as closed and migrated instead of just migrated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

This seems to be a recent thing - questions migrated are now being shown as "closed off topic" *and* "migrated to ...".

This was before the change.

[image]

This is how it looks now

[image]

Comment: Yup, this appears to be happening across the network. I see it on Stack Overflow now, too.

Comment: Possibly related: [Migration causes self-answers from asker despite other authors actually posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92455).

Comment: Updated, @M.Tibbits thanks for the headsup

Comment: Thanks.  I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @Arjan Right. It's on my to-do list :) http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/1622/my-posts-created-after-aug-17-2010-containing-stack-exchange-imgur-url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So...when a question is migrated a few things happen:

- It gets closed as off topic (this starts it all)
- It gets locked immediately (*this **wasn't** happening correctly*)
- It gets migrated (this may happen immediately, or later in a queue - for large questions)

These are all distinct things in the system, and unfortunately due to an optimization for migration performance, it made the "Locked Date" not persist correctly.  The end result of that bug was a different code path for statuses being used and some duplication that you see in the screenshot above.

This is now fixed across the network, and we cleaned up the missing LockedDate entries for those posts, you should now (like before) see a clean migrate-only status box at the bottom.

Comment: I am seeing the duplicate-post behavior today on Mi Yodeya: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/rules-regarding-the-name-of-g-od-in-the-website is on main shoing as migrated to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/rules-regarding-the-name-of-g-od-in-the-website .  One effect of this bug is that the OP still gets rep for the question on main even though the post is migrated, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - if the post gets deleted on the original site (which usually happens after some time if it really doesn't belong) the rep changes on that site will disappear.  Rep changes on deleted posts are explicitly not preserved in the cased the post was migrated away.